# what's the difference between clock_step && time reset?

Tags: ntp

why sometimes I see  clock_step but sometimes I see  time reset

log1:

```
27 Jul 11:11:08 ntpd[100258]: 0.0.0.0 c515 05 clock_sync
27 Jul 11:13:41 ntpd[100258]: 0.0.0.0 0613 03 spike_detect +4.152511 s
27 Jul 11:27:01 ntpd[100258]: 0.0.0.0 061c 0c clock_step +4.151101 s
27 Jul 11:27:05 ntpd[100258]: 0.0.0.0 0614 04 freq_mode
```

log2:

```
Apr  6 16:39:01 AAA3 ntpd[2576]: synchronized to 172.16.100.81, stratum 3
Apr  6 16:56:16 AAA3 ntpd[2576]: time reset +6.288863 s
Apr  6 16:59:49 AAA3 ntpd[2576]: synchronized to 172.16.100.81, stratum 3
```

Answer (score 1):

**time reset** : The time error exceeds the step threshold and has been reset to the correct time.

**clock_step** : Normally modifies the local system clock frequency to adjust the differences with the valid ntp servers. If the offset is greater than 128 ms, configures otherwise and will step the system clock.

also see [here](http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.0/msyslog.html)